How to setup multiple run tasks using org.openjfx.javafxplugin?
I know it is possible to create a project to run a single application class using org.openjfx.javafxplugin like so:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

javafx {
    version = '22.0.1'
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web', 'javafx.swing' ]
}

application {
    mainClass = 'my.App'
}


It configures the :run task properly and adds JavaFX dependencies.
But I need to create a few tasks to run different classes. runAppA, runAppB, etc. How do I do that?
Declaring a JavaExec task like so does not help:
tasks.register('runAppA', JavaExec) {
    group = 'application'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = 'runAppA'

    jvmArgs = [
        '--module-path', configurations.implementation.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
        '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing'
    ]
}

It gives me an error Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for configuration ':component-demos:implementation' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultUnlockedConfiguration.
How do I properly configure it?

The configurations.implementation code is giving you a Configuration1. That interface does not have a runtimeClasspath property. You probably want to use configurations.runtimeClasspath, which gives you a (resolvable) configuration that extends from runtimeOnly and implementation. See the Dependency Management section of The Java Plugin documentation for more information. And since a Configuration is a FileCollection you can simply call asPath on it. In short, the following should fix your error and (hopefully) allow your custom task to execute successfully:
jvmArgs = [
    '--module-path', configurations.runtimeClasspath.asPath,
    '--add-modules', 'javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.web,javafx.swing'
]

However, note the org.openjfx.javafxplugin plugin does things a little differently when modifying the run task. When the project is non-modular, it filters the class-path so that it includes everything except the JavaFX dependencies. Similarly, it filters the module-path so that it only includes said dependencies. Doing this is not strictly necessary but it is arguably more correct. It can also help prevent a potentially confusing IllegalAccessError at run-time due to some JavaFX modules being resolved as named modules while others are not2.

1. It actually gives you a Provider<Configuration>. At least, it does when using the Kotlin DSL, where you would have to call get() in order to actually use the Configuration. If the same is true in the Groovy DSL, then my guess is that the get() is implicit.
2. Something that can only happen when JavaFX is both on the module-path and the class-path, while simultaneously not including all needed JavaFX modules in the --add-modules argument.

Example
Here is a full example that includes the dependency filtering. Though it uses the Kotlin DSL since I'm more comfortable with it than the Groovy DSL.
Source Code
Main.java
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var root = new StackPane(new Label("Primary entry point!"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Main");
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}

AltMain.java
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AltMain extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var root = new StackPane(new Label("Alternative entry point!"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.setTitle("AltMain");
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}

Gradle Files
settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "example"

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.1.0"
    application
}

javafx {
    modules("javafx.controls")
    version = "22.0.2"
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.example.Main"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val main by sourceSets
val runtimeClasspath by configurations

tasks.register<JavaExec>("altRun") {
    group = "application"
    mainClass = "com.example.AltMain"

    classpath = main.runtimeClasspath.filter { !it.name.startsWith("javafx-")    
    val modulePath = runtimeClasspath.fileCollection { it.group == "org.openjfx" }
    jvmArgs(
        "--module-path", modulePath.asPath,
        "--add-modules", javafx.modules.joinToString(",")
    )
}

Couple notes:

The filter I used to remove the JavaFX JARs from the class-path is somewhat naive.

The Configuration::fileCollection(Spec) method was deprecated in Gradle 8.8. If using Gradle 8.8+, then I believe the replacement is:
val modulePath = runtimeClasspath.incoming.artifactView { 
    componentFilter {
        it is ModuleComponentIdentifier && it.group == "org.openjfx"
    }
}.files



